# Comparing values in dictionary in Python 3 not working?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value

I've been struggling to figure out how to access (and compare) values in a dictionary for an assignment in my Python course.

I think I understand keys and values well enough, but for some reason no matter what I try for comparing values my program never seems to see duplicate values.

Why doesn't this work?

```
  if new_value in b_dict.values():
    print("Password already exists...\n")
  else:
    add_to_dict(b_dict, new_key, new_value)
    print("\nPassword added successfully.\n")
```

Full program:

```
def add_to_dict(dict, key, value):
  if key in dict:
    dict[key].append(value)
  else:
    dict[key] = [value]

if __name__ == "__main__":
  b_dict = {"att": ["12345"]}

  new_key = input("Please enter an organization ID to add: ")

  if new_key in b_dict:
    print("Organization exists, adding to this organization...")
  if new_key not in b_dict:
    print("Organization does not exist, adding it...")

  new_value = input("Please input a password: ")

  print("Adding password...")
  if new_value in b_dict.values():
    print("Password already exists...\n")
  else:
    add_to_dict(b_dict, new_key, new_value)
    print("\nPassword added successfully.\n")

  print(b_dict)
```

I would expect that when the user enters att, followed by 12345 the program would inform them that password already exists and then print the original dictionary. Instead it always prints the dictionary with the duplicate 12345 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b_dict.values()` would contain all the values of all the keys of `b_dict` - which means, it would contain `['12345']` but not `'12345'` - I think what you need to check is

`if [new_value] in b_dict.values()`

But this would work for this particular case, and as you append new values you might need to either loop over all the keys separately or flatten out the values

Answer (score 0):

**Is this code solving your problem or not ?**

```
  if key in dict:
    dict[key].append(value)
  else:
    dict[key] = [value]

def check_values(value,key) :
    if key in b_dict :
        return value in b_dict[key]
    else : 
        return False
if __name__ == "__main__":
  b_dict = {"att": ["12345"]}

  new_key = input("Please enter an organization ID to add: ")


  new_value = input("Please input a password: ")

  
  
  if check_values(new_value,new_key) == True :

      print("They already exist..")
  elif check_values(new_value,new_key) == False :
        print("They are not exits.. adding it")
        if new_key in b_dict :


            print("this Organization's password already exist")

        else :
            print("adding new organization and password")
            add_to_dict(b_dict, new_key, new_value)

  
print(b_dict)
```

Comment: this side is not about only getting code, but about understanding it as well. Please explain your code, tell what the person asking this question did wrong. Why? How to fix it?